# How do I make bottomsheet swipe up from anywhere in scaffold flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to make a launcher in flutter, however I cannot figure out how to make a drawer that can be swiped up from the home screen, like in other launchers like nova or poco or many others. I understand that the app drawer closely matches a bottom sheet, but bottom sheets in flutter need to be first tapped on them and then dragged. How do I drag a widget up from anywhere on the scaffold?

Comment: Hi, I have the same case like yours, did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the functionality you're looking for use this package: [flutter slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)

**Example:**
**[image: output:]**

with code as simple as this you can obtain the slideup bottom sheet like functionality:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("SlidingUpPanelExample"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("This is the Widget behind the sliding panel"),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, "How do I drag a widget up from anywhere on the scaffold". The SlidingUpPanel Widget requires that you drag it by tapping on it and is visible on the screen. It won't go up if i simple drag vertically on scaffold

Comment: well I guess your question is unclear, I am not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. please consider editing your question.